# unable to print array returned by AJAX with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

```
function getWriters(cat, lev, id)   
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)

        {

            document.getElementById("writer").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            var writer = eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.write(writer)
        }


    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "order.php?op=2&id=0&cat=" + cat + "&lev=" + lev, true);
    xmlhttp.send();


}
```

xmlhttp.responseText  returns

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Unassigned [user_id] => 2 [writing_level] => [writing_category] => ) [1] => Array ( [name] => arsalan [user_id] => 3 [writing_level] => [writing_category] => ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Shazia [user_id] => 4 [writing_level] => [writing_category] => ) [3] => Array ( [name] => janea [user_id] => 5 [writing_level] => [writing_category] => ) [4] => Array ( [name] => s [user_id] => 6 [writing_level] => [writing_category] => ) [5] => Array ( [name] => iuiui [user_id] => 8 [writing_level] => [writing_category] => ) [6] => Array ( [name] => demo [user_id] => 9 [writing_level] => [writing_category] => ) [7] => Array ( [name] => wewe [user_id] => 10 [writing_level] => [writing_category] => ) [8] => Array ( [name] => Muhammad Zoyeb [user_id] => 11 [writing_level] => [writing_category] => ) [9] => Array ( [name] => Atif Rauf Alvi [user_id] => 12 [writing_level] => [writing_category] => ) [10] => Array ( [name] => demo-1 [user_id] => 13 [writing_level] => [writing_category] => ) [11] => Array ( [name] => ffff** [user_id] => 14 [writing_level] => High School,Masters [writing_category] => Literature and Language,Social Sciences ) )
```

i am getting syntax error at  document.write(writer);
if i remove eval() there is no syntax error.

Can anyone explain how to fix this or some other way to convert the string returned to array.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to use a framework like jQuery or Prototype for a real site. Install Firebug and see what you get when you `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string being returned from the server isn't valid JSON or JavaScript syntax, so you can't pass it to `eval()`.  It looks like you're using PHP's `print_r` function on the array at the server — you need to use [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) (PHP >5.2):

```
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

Then you can parse it locally with [`JSON.parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466(v=vs.85).aspx) (recommended) or `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your JSON response is the stringifed version of a PHP array. Why not return JSON from your PHP, then Javascript picks up the array natively.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the PHP "representation" of an array and by evaluating this string you fall into the syntax error.

Try this:

- Return the array from the PHP as a comma-separated string
- Explode the string in JS and put it into an array (if you need a JS array, otherwise print it and stop)

To split a string use:

```
var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
var responseArray = response.split(",");
```